# Convert JSON string from fetch to object

Tags: json, fetch-api

I need to convert my JSON response to an object, how can I achieve this?

My JSON response:

```
[  
   {  
      "id":296,
      "nama":"Appetizer"
   },
   {  
      "id":295,
      "nama":"Bahan"
   }
]
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Provided your response is a valid JSON, just do this

```
var obj = JSON.parse(response);
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to use JSON.parse in a try catch to catch errors if JSON is not valid.

```
let str = '[{"id":296,"nama":"Appetizer"},{"id":295,"nama":"Bahan"}]';

try {
  let obj = JSON.parse(str);
} catch (ex) {
  console.error(ex);
}
```

To convert back your object to string, use Stringify

```
JSON.stringify(obj)
```